# Why target is not created when I use ALB ingress controller in EKS?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I deployed a nginx container to EKS cluster. it includes a ALB ingress controller and I am able to see the ALB is created and its rule is also created. But when I click the rule to open the target group, I see there is empty under `Target` tab which means the route doesn't route any traffic to nginx container.

I am able to see the pod (`sidecar-app-6889d46d46-bns46`) is running:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
sample-es-74db8bcd65-2sq5v     1/1     Running   0          4h40m
sidecar-app-6889d46d46-bns46   1/1     Running   0          4h42m
```

The service is also look good to me:

```
$ kubectl get service
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.100.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          4d5h
sample-es-entrypoint   NodePort    10.100.57.164   <none>        9200:31987/TCP   4h41m
sidecar-entrypoint     NodePort    10.100.164.72   <none>        80:31144/TCP     4h43m
```

So what is the reason that the target is not created?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-conf
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    user nginx;
    worker_processes  1;
    events {
      worker_connections  10240;
    }
    http {
      server {
          listen       80;
          server_name  localhost;
          location /* {
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:9200/;
        }
      }
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sidecar-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:latest
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nginx-conf
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
              subPath: nginx.conf
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-conf
          configMap:
            name: nginx-conf
            items:
              - key: nginx.conf
                path: nginx.conf

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sidecar-entrypoint
spec:
  selector:
    name: sidecar-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sidecar-ingress-1
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: sidecar-ingress
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: '2'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: sidecar-entrypoint
              servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

After did some debugging, the issue is the match label in my configuration is wrong `app: nginx`, which should be `name: sidecar-app`

Comment: Thanks also had issues with incorrect match labels